# How to display viewbag on view on HttpPost

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to display the ViewBag on view on button click event, this is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SpecificWorkflowReport(Report2ListViewModel wf)
{

  var getSpRecord = db.Mworkflow().ToList();

  var getRecord = (from u in getSpRecord
   select new Report2ListViewModel
      {
        WorkFlowType = u.WorkFlowType,
        WorkflowInstanceId = u.WorkflowInst,
        WorkFlowDescription = u.WorkFlowDesc,
      }).ToList();

      ViewBag.WorkflowType = wf.WorkFlowType;
      ViewBag.WorkflowInstanceId = wf.WorkflowInst;
      ViewBag.WorkFlowDescription = wf.WorkFlowDesc

      var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getRecord);
      return Json(data);
}
```

i have tried this:

```
Worflow Type: @ViewBag.WorkflowType
Workflow Instance Id: @ViewBag.WorkflowInstanceId
Workflow Description: @ViewBag.WorkFlowDescription
```

My Javascript and json Call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var table = $("#reportTable").DataTable();
        var url = $("#frmSpecificWorkflowReport").attr('action');
        var str = $("#frmSpecificWorkflowReport").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (_data) {

                if (_data.f !== undefined) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Empty Result Set",
                        text: "No record found",
                        type: "info"
                    });
                    table.clear();
                    return false;
                }

                var arr = $.map(JSON.parse(_data), function (el) { return el 
            });
                if (arr.length === 0) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Empty Result Set",
                        text: "No record found",
                        type: "info"
                    });
                }
                table.clear();
                table.destroy();
                $('#reportTable').dataTable({
                    data: arr,
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "WorkFlowType" },
                        { "data": "WorkflowInstanceId" },
                        { "data": "WorkFlowDescription" },

                    ],
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel',
                        {
                            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                            orientation: 'landscape',
                            pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                        }

                    ]
                });
                table = $("#reportTable").DataTable();
```

but the ViewBag values are always null on the view, any assistance will be appreciated. I just added Javascript and json call to the post, i want to be able to retrieve my stored data and display it anywhere on the view

Comment: `return Json(data);` => you're returning JSON data instead of a view, that's maybe a reason why `ViewBag` is null since the view is not immediately returned by action method.

Comment: You would need to pass those vales in your `JsonResult` and read them in the ajax call back and update the elements in the DOM

Comment: But there seems no need to do that, since they are exactly the same values that you just sent from the client to the server - you already know what they are in the client.

Comment: @UwakkPeter see the given answer

Comment: And why are you using `.SerializeObject()` - calling `return Json(); already serializes it, so your now doing it twice (and would need to unnecessarily parse it back on the client)

Answer (score 0):

@UwakPeter your code snippets is ok, but you are returning Json, may be you are calling this method via javascript, so the view is not updating, you need to **reload the view**, by the submit button.

If you are using javascript, you can pass your data list and model data as anonymous object, so that you don't need to use ViewBag. in client side by ajax success function you can grab them (**WorkflowType, WorkflowInstanceId, WorkFlowDescription, Result**)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SpecificWorkflowReport(Report2ListViewModel wf)
{
    var getSpRecord = db.Mworkflow().ToList();

    var getRecord = (from u in getSpRecord
    select new Report2ListViewModel
    {
        WorkFlowType = u.WorkFlowType,
        WorkflowInstanceId = u.WorkflowInst,
        WorkFlowDescription = u.WorkFlowDesc,
    }).ToList();

    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getRecord);
    return Json(new{
        WorkflowType = wf.WorkFlowType,
        WorkflowInstanceId = wf.WorkflowInst,
        WorkFlowDescription = wf.WorkFlowDesc,
        Result= data 
    }, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: str,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (_data) {
            var workflowType=_data.WorkflowType; //set it to HTML control
            var workflowInstanceId =_data.WorkflowInstanceId;
            var workFlowDescription  = _data.WorkFlowDescription;
            $('#reportTable').dataTable({
                data: _data.Result
            });
        }

)};
```

Comment: I just added my javascript function to the post, could you please show me how this could be achieved

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
@{  
    Layout = null;  
    ProjectMVC.Models.Record record= (ProjectMVC.Models.Record)ViewBag.Recorddetails;
}
...
Worflow Type: @record.WorkflowType
```

Comment: where is ViewBag.Recorddetails from?